# OTA design, the Gm won't go down to zero

Tags: differential, transconductance, ota

I'm trying to simulate a pseudo-differential OTA, but the the Gm vs Vin(differential) plot I obtain seems warped. The Gm won't go down to zero for large values of Vin.

[image]

[image]

attached is the circuit schematic, and the waveform. The top waveform is the Gm vs Vin(differential) plot and bottom is the current.

this is done in 65nm CMOS.

the Gm plot should be symmetrical on both sides, and so what could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: 1) *a pseudo-differential OTA* so it isn't fully differential, so why do you expect it to have symmetric behavior then? 2) The NMOS M37 and M38 aren't matched, M38 using inp will increase the biasing over CMFF more than M37 will. I suggest plotting the Id of M36 and see if it has a symmetrical shape (my guess: it does not). Fix that and then check again.

Comment: hi, so would say that this output would be okay for a pseudo differential OTA? I can't find any literature that talks about pseudo-differential structures in detail

Comment: What do you think **is/ makes** a pseudo differential OTA? Pseudo differential usually refers to signals where there is also a common mode component present. A true differential signal has a common mode that is zero or just a DC value, there is no signal on it.

Comment: A pseudo-diffrential OTA is one where two single ended OTAs are used in such a way that it results in a double ended output.

Comment: *A pseudo-diffrential OTA is one...* I agree with that answer. Your schematic isn't fitting that description 100% since (part of) their biasing is combined (M37, M38) and there is also some commonmode regulation going on at the output (R40, R41). It the two OTAs are exactly identical then the simulated curve must be symmetric. Have you tried making M37, M38 symmetric?

Comment: yes, the waveform distorts even more, but the same thing happens, the transconductance won't go down to zero within the range. What else could be causing this?

Comment: It is unclear to me how you're testing this circuit, you might want to include a screendump of the testbench you're using. Why do you expect the gm to become zero? Usually for OTAs we're interested in keeping a constant gm over (differential) input signal swing and over commonmode input voltage.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the testbench I am using. Actually, I am doing this for a paper, and I would need to either explain the Gm waveform, or to mitigate this problem. Do you have any source (textbook, journal publications) that can help me explain that is isn't a problem at all? Thanks.

Comment: *I am doing this for a paper* Hmm, then I would expect you to be able to "dream" this OTA. And there you have me explaining it to you. I did my Msc Thesis on a constant gm (over common mode) OTA (in CMOS) 24 years ago ;-) I do not understand why you apply the input voltage like that, you appear to apply a 0 - 2 V DC voltage but inn is fixed at Vcmm. To get a symmetrical transfer you should apply a real diff. input signal.

Comment: oh actually I am an undergrad student, so I am very sorry for my shallow knowledge on this topic. The input voltage source is just like that but I used a dc sweep on V14 to obtain my differential voltages.

Comment: Again: this will **not** give you a differential input voltage. What you do: Vinn = Vcmm (fixed, does not change) and Vinp = Vcmm + Vsweepdc  where Vsweepdc = 0 to 2 V. In a truly diff. signal Vinn would go down (in voltage) as much as Vinp goes up. I use a VCVS for that. I added an answer to show how this is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input voltage isn't truly differentail as Vinn stays fixed while Vinp varies.

To fix that use this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKhbJf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>